# Search for string, split, and show duplicate results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Suppose we have a database as such for a car park allocation sheet with owner:
`PE3739 @ B211 (Mandy F| KR1234 @ B212 (Felicity J | KR1234 (June B`

Let's suppose the search criteria is cell `B17` and we would like to find the owner

Upon when `B17` contains "PE3739" it will return `Mandy F`

However, when one car has two owners as for example when `B17` is `KR1234` I would like it so that what returns is
`Felicity J | June B`

If it is possible, this would be a massive help, I do not know how to get around this, I have tried using many ways as possible logically but I do not have the capabilities on Google Sheets.

If you can help it would be a massive favor

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution

Comment: I have specifically instructed not to due to privacy. But for you, I risk my email out. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GfDEleTQda3IIJAnZ-IVHEAgZ242yFnOQ1EvNYDAIa4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You may just give out ***view access*** to the test sheet (instead of *edit* rights) OR from next on you can use this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by the docs community forum

Comment: It's made regardless. Please check out the realistic demo data :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,'Licence Plate Database'!A:Z,
     Λ,index(if(iferror(search(B17,Σ)),regexextract(Σ,"\((.*)"),)),
       if(counta(Λ)=0,,torow(Λ,1)))
```

[image]

*Updated answer to allocate different format of `PE3739 @ B211 (Toyota (Mandy F` as well*

```js
=let(Σ,'Licence Plate Database'!A:Z,
     Λ,index(if(iferror(search(B17,Σ)),regexextract(Σ,"[^\(]*$"),)),
       if(counta(Λ)=0,,torow(Λ,1)))
```

*Updated_2 `only consider uniques`*

```js
=let(Σ,'Licence Plate Database'!A:Z,
     Λ,index(if(iferror(search(B17,Σ)),regexextract(Σ,"[^\(]*$"),)),
       if(or(counta(Λ)=0,B17=""),,unique(torow(Λ,1),1)))
```

Comment: Apologies, I found a mistake in formatitng. Is there a way to accomodate the updated where the new file format is ```PE3739 @ B211 (Toyota (Mandy F ```?

Comment: Try the updated formula added to the answer.

Comment: Awesome! But I am getting duplicates (as the same occurrence happens more than once in cases such as the same car being in a different spot and being registered as a new car (faulty system... i know), is there a way to fix that too...?

Comment: Added updated formula above...